# OrientDB traverse specific path

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, traversal

I have a couple of vertices (with property value) connected with edges in OrientDB such as:

```
              X[value=0] ------------->Y[value=0]        
                  ^                        \
                 /                          v
A[value=1] -> B[value=1] -> C[value=1] -> D[value=1] -> E[value=1]
```

I now want to have the following traverse condition:

- continue following vertices with value=1
- if you find 2 paths, only follow path along value=0

The query on the vertices above should therefore return:
A,B,X,Y,D,E (C ignored and not visited)

How is that realizable in orientdb?

Comment: i've tried with 
SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE out("EDGENAME")[value=min(out("EDGENAME").value)] FROM #78:10) but it results in a nullpointer exception when i use "min"